# How to find whether BrowserFrame has finished loading the web page

Tags: vaadin

I am using Vaadin BrowserFrame to view a web page . Is there any way I can find out programmatically that BrowserFrame has done with loading stuff ? Any event is fired when it is over ?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in core Vaadin, no.

A `BrowserFrame` component results in an `<iframe>` being created. I imagine you could create a [component extension](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20component%20extension) to hook into the javascript `onload` function for the iframe - shouldn't be too tricky, but will involved some GWT/javascript programming.